# Heroku push is being rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

I have seen similar questions but none of them have answer my problem, this one is the more similar [Heroku Bundle Error (Rails App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256247/heroku-bundle-error-rails-app#_=_) 
The issue is the same, but the answer is not. The console error is the following

```
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using 
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
```

I'm using 'rails', '4.0.0.rc1' on my gem file, and it says above ruby-1.9.3

So why is the error, why is not being pushed.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Could be that you are having problems with the ruby version.
If you don't specify, Heroku will use the default ruby version. 
Until recently it was 1.93, and as of not too long ago, it is 2.0.
To tell Heroku which version of ruby you want to use, simply put at the top of your gemfile (just below the source) ruby and the version.
After that, include the rails gem with a version.
So the top of your gemfile should look something like this, with the correct version numbers:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
```