# Unable to push app to heroku... env: bundle: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Have had an app up and working for some time, but now I cannot git push:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3-p125
-----> Installing dependencies using 
       Fixing nokogiri install. Clearing bundler cache.
       See https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/923.
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       env: bundle: No such file or directory
       Bundler Output: env: bundle: No such file or directory
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

I checked the path per https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/commit/00ae3eb09522028b692bfda15d4089b5531f0b79 and heroku config reports:

```
GEM_PATH:                   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
LANG:                       en_US.UTF-8
PATH:                       bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

so it looks like the path is correct, although I don't understand why it's ruby 1.9.1 when I'm using 1.9.3.

Gemfile contains:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~>3.2'
```

FWIW I have tried a bundle update and comitted the change to gemfile.lock, but still unable to push it.

Answer (score 1):

[Heroku push is being rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076554/heroku-push-is-being-rejected?rq=1) recommended adding ruby version to gemfile, while another post said to take it out.  Out of desperation, I tried it:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"
gem 'rails', '~>3.2'
```

Then I did a bundle update (was probably unnecessary) and pushed it:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
       Old: ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-linux]
       New: ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
       Fixing nokogiri install. Clearing bundler cache.
       See https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/923.
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing rake (10.1.0)

       ...
```

Success!  ...until I hit the next problem, but it's unrelated to this post.

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened because I had a really old environment variable that referenced a previous Ruby version:

```
PATH:      bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

I just removed it and everything started working:

```
heroku config:remove PATH
```