# Error while deploying rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Hi i was trying to learn ruby on rail from ruby.railstutorial.org and was stuck at the point of deployment of my app on heroku.When i run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

i get this error:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.3917
/usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
```

My ruby -v is 
    ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
and rails -v
    Rails 4.0.0

Here is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
  gem 'rspec-rails',      ">= 2.0.0.beta"
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. 
gem 'turbolinks'

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

group :production do

 gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
```

Why is it giving an error for ruby 1.9.1 when i am using 1.9.3 ?

Comment: this could help http://stackoverflow.com/a/16256604/1197775.