# Heroku ruby versions mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am having a problem with Heroku and a Rails app. In my Gemfile I specify `ruby "2.1.5"` but my app crashes with the following log:

```
2015-04-08T20:54:15.248878+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 57371 -e production`
2015-04-08T20:54:17.365771+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/definition.rb:380:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.5 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
2015-04-08T20:54:17.365791+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler.rb:118:in 'setup'

2015-04-08T20:54:17.365793+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in 'top (required)'

2015-04-08T20:54:17.365795+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'

2015-04-08T20:54:17.365796+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'
2015-04-08T20:54:17.365798+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/boot.rb:3:in '<top (required)>'
2015-04-08T20:54:17.365800+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:7:in 'require_relative'
2015-04-08T20:54:17.365802+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:7:in <main>

2015-04-08T20:54:18.135689+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2015-04-08T20:54:18.155346+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-08T20:54:41.881395+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=....herokuapp.com request_id=1ec36521-d1ca-4ea3-b635-b79caf9b82c9 fwd="x.x.x.x" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

and here are a few weird results of commands:

`heroku run ruby -v: ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]`

`heroku run bundle install: Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.5 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)`

Everything was fine before I switched my Gemfile from 1.9.3 to 2.1.5. Any help is appreciated. Also, it does not look like Heroku is using rvm, so I have no idea how they do their magic.

**EDIT:** I already tried deleting the app and creating a fresh, new one with version `2.1.5` (and then later `2.2.0`) in the Gemfile from the beginning (though I synced it from the same git repo).

**EDIT 2:** It does *not* actually crash on deploy, rather only on page serving, and when running `bundle(r)`. (so far)

**EDIT 3:** Every time I deploy, heroku starts with:

```
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.1.5
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.7.12
remote:        Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
remote:        Old: ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]
remote:        New: ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendo
```

(with correct versions for old/new)

**EDIT 4:** it seems that Heroku is not loading the environment variables correctly (or is it?), and so the wrong ruby version is loaded and used:

```
local$ heroku config -s | grep PATH
PATH=/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/app/bin:/app/vendor/bundle/bin
local$ heroku run ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]
local$ heroku run bash
heroku $ echo $PATH
/app/bin:/app/vendor/bundle/bin:/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0    /bin:/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0    /bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/app/bin:/app/vendor/bundle/bin
heroku $ cat .profile.d/ruby.sh | grep PATH
export GEM_PATH="$HOME/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0:$GEM_PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/vendor/bundle/bin:$HOME/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin:$PATH"
```

The environment is looking for `ruby` in `/app/bin` instead of `/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/bin`. If, in the Heroku environment, I `export PATH` to the correct values, I can run `bundle` with no problem. Unfortunately, it seems that the instance serving the app is not.

I could either change the `PATH` in `profile.d/ruby.sh` or create the `.ruby-version` file, though neither nano, nor pico nor vim are available on heroku. How am I supposed to?

Comment: Are you getting this error when deploying?

Comment: this could help you https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

Comment: @forthowin: Thanks, I already tried adding the binaries to the `PATH`, but unfortunately it has no effect.

Comment: are you using rvm? install the same ruby version there then run bundle

Comment: I am using rvm, and I did that. On my side everything is fine, I can run a local server. Only heroky crashes.

Comment: @infused : I just checked, it also crashes right after pushing (without any page load). So : deploy, page load, bundle commands

Comment: what does running ruby -v give you? and do rvm list to make sure you're using the right version

Comment: @forthowin : Do you want me to run those command in my local environment, or on Heroku? `ruby -v` on Heroku gives me 2.1.5 (see post) and `rvm` is not installed.

Comment: Ignore my answer about `.ruby-version`: that was a fix for a local rvm problem not heroku. I have to admit I don't remember exactly what fixed it, but I think you are on the right track with changing the path.

Comment: Have you already tried: `heroku config:set PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` ?

Comment: Yes I did, see edit 4. I read the correct values with `heroku config -s` but  note from 'within' `heroku run bash`.

Comment: Actually it looks like your path is what its supposed to be, mine is the same and it runs fine. Also you dont need to run `heroku run bundle install`. All you need to do is run it locally to generate the `Gemfile.lock` and then push to heroku so `bundle` not working is not a problem you need to worry about. See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler.

For the other page not serving issue, are you manually running the command: `heroku run bin/rails server -p 57371 -e production`?

Comment: @Sid Thanks for the PATH, it's good to know. And no, I just `git push heroku master`, and heroku starts the server by itself.

Comment: @Sid if the PATH is normal, how come does heroku references a `2.1.0` version of ruby, then a `1.9.1` version, but never `2.1.5` (first quote, original post)? Also, since I started a fresh app, and that other people are running `2.1.5` without any problem, where could it come from in my repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, 48 hours later, I found the solution here : [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256247/heroku-bundle-error-rails-app).

Indeed, there was some leftover crap in my project, namely in the `bin` folder. Here's what solved it:

`$ bundle config --delete bin`

`$ bundle exec rake rails:update:bin`

all localy. Then push to heroku, without forgetting to include the newly generated files. Hurray!

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into a related issue involving a ruby version mismatch when deploying to Heroku. The issue was a conflicting version of bundler. Heroku locks each buildpack to a specific version of bundler.

To fix, update bundler `gem update bundler`, `bundle install` and deploy again.

More here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version

Comment: that fixed my Gemfile.lock file. Thanks